# windows azure: exception while setting a filter for a subscription

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I try to create a subscription and set a filter for that subscription, but the createRule method raise an exception. Any idea about how to fix it? Thanks.

```
SubscriptionInfo subInfo1 = new SubscriptionInfo("High_Ages"); 
CreateSubscriptionResult result1 = serviceBusContract.createSubscription(topicName, subInfo1); 
ruleInfo1 = ruleInfo1.withSqlExpressionFilter("user_age >= 50"); 
CreateRuleResult ruleResult = serviceBusContract.createRule(topicName, "High_Ages", ruleInfo1);
```

the method createRule(topicName,"High_Ages", ruleInfo1) raise the following exception

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path segment is null
    com.sun.jersey.api.uri.UriBuilderImpl.appendPath(UriBuilderImpl.java:499)
    com.sun.jersey.api.uri.UriBuilderImpl.appendPath(UriBuilderImpl.java:494)
    com.sun.jersey.api.uri.UriBuilderImpl.path(UriBuilderImpl.java:254)
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.path(WebResource.java:390)
    com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.serviceBus.implementation.ServiceBusRestProxy.createRule(ServiceBusRestProxy.java:361)
    com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.serviceBus.implementation.ServiceBusExceptionProcessor.createRule(ServiceBusExceptionProcessor.java:346)`

Comment: It seems it is a topic related error so I would check if the topic is created already and accessible. Use listTopics method on ServiceBusContract objects to check if a topic with a specified name already exists within a service namespace and try to Create a Rule.

Comment: Yes, I've already try this. The topics is created. I've used the listTopics method and even the management portal to confirm it. But the exception still remain :(